# The new GFCI outlet is not working!

Tags: gfci

I live in New Hampshire, U.S.

I am trying to add a light and a GFCI outlet in a bathroom.

I have a GFCI outlet in the line first from the source.  The outlet and switch are in the same double box.  The switch and light work fine.

From the GFCI outlet running to another outlet receptacle in the kitchen.  Both outlets are not working.  I connected the wires running to the other outlet to the GFCI outlet load screws and this should work but does not.  Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring inside the box?

Comment: Does "not working" mean trips?  Or does "not working" mean dead as a doornail in all modes including pushing the RESET button?

Answer (score 2):

With GFCIs, the rule is "one step at a time".

Disconnect the GFCI except for the ground wire.   Tape or cap the dangling wires.   OK, assuming you want the light not on the GFCI,  does the light work?

Now connect only the LINE side of the GFCI.   Does that work?  If it fails, how?   If it's just dead, it's a bum GFCI and go get a good one from a better store.  There's a reason electricians don't buy from big-box.

Ok so it all works.  Now hang the remaining outlet(s) on the LOAD side of the GFCI.  Generally this means attaching exactly 2 wires from 1 cable.  If any problems arise, you know what it isn't.

Watch your neutrals.